# Why doesn't the linux kernel #include<stdint.h> when I #include<arm_neon.h>?

Tags: linux, gcc, neon

When I want to add the header file arm_neon.h in the kernel code throws an error

```
gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-4.3.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/include/arm_neon.h:45:20: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
```

but including the same file in the user space doesn't do it.

From this reference,

> ### NEON intrinsics
>
> NEON intrinsics are also supported. However, as code using NEON intrinsics
>   relies on the GCC header `<arm_neon.h>`, (which `#includes <stdint.h>`), you should observe the following in addition to the rules above:
>
> - Compile the unit containing the NEON intrinsics with '-ffreestanding' so GCC uses its builtin version of `<stdint.h>` (this is a C99 header which the kernel does not supply);
> - Include `<arm_neon.h>` last, or at least after `<linux/types.h>`

I've added the `-ffreestanding` option, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Why are you using a 10-year-old version of GCC?

Comment: Grab GCC7.x at linaro.org; All problems solved.

Comment: I'm curious, isn't it dangerous using NEON at the kernel level?

Comment: @nemequ client's code.. client's version of gcc.. even the kernel is of version 3.4.y I need to migrate to a newer version.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Thanks. I'll grab a newer version of gcc.. It isn't good but if required, they provide a way of using it.. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/kernel_mode_neon.txt